# Link dynamically against Public\Qt inside ocean

Tags: qt, ocean

Using Petrel 2016.1

Libraries reference:
https://www.ocean.slb.com/~/media/files/testing%20plug%20ins/libraries/petrel_2016-1_3rd_party_libraries.html

My plugin uses Qt for a window and some plots with qwt. I would like to link against the Qt dlls present at Petrel\Public\Qt to save some space while deploying the app and because is not possible to deploy libs already present in Petrel as public libs by policy.
I've successfully linked with the same Qt version over there. The problem is that PluginPackager.exe does not see the libs. I've tried editing PluginPackager.exe.config inside Petrel dir to include Public\Qt, copied it to the Release folder, copied it to the main project folder and every dir that I may suspect PluginPackager.exe is looking for this file but nothing seems to cause any effect.

I've copied the Qt dlls to the Release folder, so PluginPackager.exe could see them and register the Plugin. It works, even if I delete the Qt dlls from the Release folder afterwards. Petrel is loading them from Public\Qt. The problem is that when I try to open the Qt window, a message saying that Qt failed to load plugin windows.

I figured that it is related to qwindows.dll, which is inside Public\Qt\plugins\platforms. If I set the environment variable QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH to C:..\petrel...\Public\Qt\plugins\platforms, it works fine. I've tried to use addLibraryPath() from QApplication with no success.

I guess we have everything we need inside Public\Qt, but for some reason Petrel is not finding it. Two questions, then:

1- How to make PluginPackager to see all the libs inside Public\Qt?

2- How to make my application to find qwindows.dll?

Plugin has code in C#, C++ cli and C++

**EDIT 1:**
Ok, for Q.2 I've found a solution by trial and error.

```
QString path = QDir::currentPath();
QString finalPath = QDir(path).filePath("Public/Qt/plugins");
QApplication::addLibraryPath(finalPath);
```

This will add the plugins dir to the qt lib search path and does the trick. I hope I can deploy using this.

**EDIT 2:**
For Q.1

I realize now that the PluginPackager only sees things inside the Extensions folder. The problem was that, in my opinion, the folder name Public is misleading. This led me to think that all libs inside that folder could be used by developers freely. The Ocean guide states that all libs other than the ones inside Extensions are considered internal libs:

> The PluginPackager.exe assumes that files in the Petrel installation directory tree other than those in the Extensions folder are internal Petrel libraries.

Well, why name a folder Public if all the libs inside it are internal? This is really confusing. Besides, the Slb.Ocean libs inside the Public folders are Ok to use, the others are not? As PluginPackager.exe.config has Public\ but not the folders inside it.